# function never ends - fileReader xlsx.js angularJS

Tags: angularjs, function, filereader

I'm using the FileReader Object in combination with xlsx.js to import data from an Excel-Sheet into my AngularJS Web-App.

The function never gets ended, so I need to continue the script manually by invoking an empty dummy function check(){} manually by clicking on a button to continue my script. I don't know, why the script behaves like that.

Code of my controller:

```
$scope.fileChanged = function(files) {
    var i,f;
    f = files[0];
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {

        var data = e.target.result;
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
        formData.data.teams = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets['latusch']);
        var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;

        var worksheet = workbook.Sheets['latusch'];
        var result = {};
        workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
            var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
            if(roa.length > 0){
                result[sheetName] = roa;
            }
        });
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`readAsArrayBuffer` is inside the onload callback, so it will not be called.
Remove it from the callback.